# python, cleaning a list

Tags: python, string

Trying to clean up a python list,  I am able to remove exact string matches.  How do I remove partial matches?

```
exclude = ['\n','Hits','Sites','blah','blah2','partial string','maybe here']
newlist = []
for item in array:
    if item not in exclude:
        newlist.append(item)
```

Problem here is "item not in exclude"... which does exact matching.

Should I use the following method:

```
s = "This be a string"
if s.find("is") == -1:
    print "No 'is' here!"
else:
    print "Found 'is' in the string."
```

In a way i answered my own question :)  I guess is there an operand alternative to 'in' ?

Thanks

Comment: It is not very clear, what you want. Also, what is `array` that you have defined in your code above?

Comment: This clearly depends on the definition of "partial match": What is considered a match and what isn't?

Comment: string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are searching for?

```
blacklist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
cleaned = []
for item in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']:
    clean = True
    for exclude in blacklist:
        if item.find(exclude) != -1:
            clean = False
            break
    if clean:
        cleaned.append(item)
print cleaned # --> ['foo']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following generator instead:

```
def remove_similar(array, exclude):
    for item in array:
        for fault in exclude:
            if fault in item:
                break
        else:
            yield item
```

Comment: yes, but this only removes exact matches... how would i search for partial matches?

Comment: You might want to test it: `list(remove_similar(['a', 'b', 'ab', 'c', 'ac', 'bc', 'abc'], ['a']))` This returns the list `['b', 'c', 'bc']`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking here.  Do you want to filter out all elements in `array` that are substrings of an element of `exclude`?  If so, you could replace your line

```
if item not in exclude:
```

with something like

```
if not any(item in e for e in exclude):
```

Comment: uhm... im trying to catch partial and exact matches...  if that makes sense :)

Comment: what does it mean for string `a` to be a "partial match" of string `b`? I interpreted it to mean "`a` is a substring of `b`".  I think others are also confused about this.

Comment: what I am trying to do is this : string.find(s)

Comment: i want the loop to go through the exclude list and find any partial matches, not exact matches

Answer (score 1):

```
exclude = ['\n','Hits','Sites','blah','blah2','partial string','maybe here']
newlist = []
for item in array:
        ok = True
        for excItem in exclude:
                if excItem in item: 
                    ok = False
                    break
        if ok: newlist.append(item)
```

Comment: thanks!  but this does not match partial things, only exact matches...  How would i get that going?

Comment: +1 because it's close enough to what the OP wanted given the vagueness of "partial match".

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
all( s.find(e) == -1 for e in exclude )
```

which will return `True` if none of the exclude strings are found as substrings in `s`.

---

if by partial you mean that `s` is a substring of `e`, then:

```
not any( e.find(s) != -1 for e in exclude )
```

would return `True` if `s` is not found as a substring in any of the strings in `exclude`

Comment: what about partial matches?  I want to be able to catch strings that match exactly, and partially

Comment: If he actually needs the list for some reason, the above could easily be modified to generate it as well.

Comment: having trouble putting that into python :)