# Native Python function to remove NoneType elements from list?

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I'm using Beautiful Soup in Python to scrape some data from HTML files. In some cases, Beautiful Soup returns lists that contain both `string` and `NoneType` objects. I'd like to filter out all the `NoneType` objects.

In Python, lists with containing `NoneType` objects are not iterable, so list comprehension isn't an option for this. Specifically, if I have a list `lis` containing `NoneTypes`, and I try to do something like `[x for x in lis (some condition/function)]`, Python throws the error `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`.

As we've seen in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458006/python-cleaning-a-list), it's straightforward to implement this functionality in a user-defined function. Here's my flavor of it:

```
def filterNoneType(lis):
    lis2 = []
    for l in links: #filter out NoneType
        if type(l) == str:
            lis2.append(l)
    return lis2
```

However, I'd love to use a built-in Python function for this if it exists. I always like to simplify my code when possible. **Does Python have a built-in function that can remove `NoneType` objects from lists?**

Comment: You are wrong that lists containing `None` are not iterable. You are probably (accidentally) trying to iterate over `None` itself: `[x for x in None]`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I think the cleanest way to do this would be:

```
#lis = some list with NoneType's
filter(None, lis)
```

Comment: This is wrong, because it will also remove `0`, `False` and `''` elements.

Comment: Fair enough.  You can use `filter(lambda x: x!=None, lis)` then.

Comment: @Abs, is `filter` the appropriate way delete key-value pairs with `None` values from dicts?

Comment: `filter` doesn't actually modify anything - it creates a new, filtered dict. to actually delete a key-value pair, you'll want to use `del`. For example: `del(somedict[key_to_delete])` will delete a key from a dict.

Comment: This is more pedantically correct: `lambda x: x is not None`

Comment: From the docs: Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to the generator expression (item for item in iterable if function(item)) if function is not None and (item for item in iterable if item) if function is None.

Answer (score 28):

You can do this using list comprehension:

```
clean = [x for x in lis if x != None]
```

As pointed in the comments you could also use `is not`, even if it essentially compiles to the same bytecode:

```
clean = [x for x in lis if x is not None]
```

You could also used `filter` (note: this will also filter empty strings, if you want more control over what you filter you can pass a function instead of `None`):

```
clean = filter(None, lis)
```

There is always the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) approach if you want more efficient looping, but these basic approaches should work for most day to day cases.

Comment: As per PEP 8 you should use `is not` rather than `!=` when comparing with singletons.

Comment: filter() takes a function as first argument

Comment: @ThorstenKranz if the first param is `None` it filters out all `False`-like entries (`None`, empty strings, zeros etc).

Comment: @ThorstenKranz `filter` with None will remove all None entries from a list and is more efficient than passing a lambda function which will be slower.

Comment: @CharlesMenguy the only problem is that it will also remove empty strings (which actually may be not a problem, since OP is going to iterate over those and likely to ignore them in any case).

Comment: @CharlesMenguy, it will also remove an empty str that is not NoneType.Not sure if it's a problem though.

Comment: Good point, I usually don't care when using this approach, but I'm adding that as a drawback.

Comment: @CharlesMenguy note that you can just do [x for x in lis if x], which is simpler, and slightly faster if you profile it

Answer (score 7):

List comprehension, as other answers proposed or, for the sake of completeness:

```
clean = filter(lambda x: x is not None, lis)
```

If the list is huge, an iterator approach is superior:

```
from itertools import ifilter
clean = ifilter(lambda x: x is not None, lis)
```

Comment: A general note for future readers: In Python3, `filter` **already** returns an iterator so the sceond approach is not necessary. It is only relevant for Python 2. If you actually want a list using Python 3, just do `list(filter(...))`

Answer (score 7):

### For those who came here from Google — do not use this!

**UPD 2021:**
When this answer was written, the proposed implementation was absolutely valid in terms of language semantics yet being an obvious hack. Things has changed since then and starting from Python 3.9 evaluation of `NotImplemented` in boolean context is explicitly discouraged. Here an excerpt from Python docs:

> Evaluating NotImplemented in a boolean context is deprecated. While it currently evaluates as true, it will emit a DeprecationWarning. It will raise a TypeError in a future version of Python.

I will keep this answer for the sake of history but please be aware that even in it's time this was kinda hacky. Stick to proposed list comprehension solutions or `filter`+`lambda` according to your requirements.

**Original answer:**
As of the beginning of 2019, Python has no built-in function for filtering None values which avoids common pitfals with deleting zeroes, empty strings, etc.

In Python3 you can implement this using  `.__ne__` dunder method (or 'magic method' if you will):

```
>>> list1 = [0, 'foo', '', 512, None, 0, 'bar']
>>> list(filter(None.__ne__, list1))
[0, 'foo', '', 512, 0, 'bar']
```

This is how it works:

- `None.__ne__(None)` --> False
- `None.__ne__(anything)` --> NotImplemented

`NotImplemented` exeption effectively is `True`, e.g.:

```
>>> bool(None.__ne__('Something'))
True
```

Comment: Using dunder methods in filter is anything but elegant. It's an ugly hack. List comprehensions are much preferred in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily remove all `NoneType` objects from a list using a list comprehension:

```
lis = [i for i in lis if i is not None]
```