# Remove NoneType from two lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, nonetype

I'm working with two `np.arrays` of equal lengths. One of them contains `None` elements. I would like to remove these from that array and also from the corresponding elements in the other array.

Naively I thought this would do:

```
ToFRemove = (None == ListA)  # Find None type                          

ListA = ListA[not ToFRemove]
ListB = ListB[not ToFRemove]
```

This works for finding other regular elements. However, I get `False` as the value of `ToFRemove` so this does not work.

I assume I should write some iterator to find the elements that are `None` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14229471/5408884) but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this

`np_array[np_array != np.array(None)]`

The statement np_array != np.array(None) outputs a boolean array. This boolean array would have 'False' where ever the element is of 'None' type and True for others. Indexes corresponding to 'True' remain in the resultant array and those corresponding to 'False' is removed.

Applying this to your problem

```
ToKeep = (ListA != np.array(None))
ListA = ListA[ToKeep]
ListB = ListA[ToKeep]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ToFRemove = np.array([x is None for x in ListA])
```