# While creating a CSV format data the list is throwing error

Tags: python

I have a list as follows:

```
sample = ['a', 'b', 'c', None]
```

My Code is :

```
sample_out = ','.join(sample)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 3: expected string, NoneType found
```

Could someone point me out how to handle the `None`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join a list of items with different types as string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590165/join-a-list-of-items-with-different-types-as-string-in-python)

Comment: You didn't specify how you actually **want** to *handle* the `None`... Do you want to add it to the string? Filter it out? print a warning?

Comment: if you could provide the expected output that would make things easier

Comment: I would filter out the None and result would be like a,b,c

Comment: In that case, here is the correct dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229433/native-python-function-to-remove-nonetype-elements-from-list

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
sample_out = ','.join([x if x else "" for x in sample])
```